# Future geolocate method rewrite not updating record

Tags: trigger, api, google

I followed some advice on how to avoid the future callout 51 error.  I turned the code into a list, and within the future method I add it to a map, and once loop is done I update the map.  However nothing updates for me and I cannot figure out why.  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B2h8IAC had the same issue.

```
    trigger SetGeolocation on Account (after insert, after update) {
    if(!system.isFuture() && !system.isBatch())

    {
        List<Id> calloutIds = new List<Id>();    
        for (Account a : trigger.new)
            {

                calloutIds.add(a.id);
            }
    LocationCallouts.getLocation(calloutIds);
    }

    }
```

Now for the method.

```
    public class LocationCallouts {

         @future (callout=true)  // future method needed to run callouts from Triggers
          static public void getLocation(List<Id> accountIds){
            Map<ID,Account> account_updater = new Map<ID,Account>();
            // gather account info
            for (Account a: [SELECT BillingCity,BillingCountry,BillingPostalCode,BillingState,BillingStreet,JYF__Location__Longitude__s ,JYF__Location__Latitude__s  FROM Account WHERE id in : accountIds] ) 
     {
                // create an address string
                String address = '';
                if (a.BillingStreet != null)
                    address += a.BillingStreet +', ';
                if (a.BillingCity != null)
                    address += a.BillingCity +', ';
                if (a.BillingState != null)
                    address += a.BillingState +' ';
                if (a.BillingPostalCode != null)
                    address += a.BillingPostalCode +', ';
                if (a.BillingCountry != null)
                    address += a.BillingCountry;

                address = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8');

                // build callout
                Http h = new Http();
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
               //Erased my API key but this is usually filled in                    
               req.setEndpoint('empty');

                req.setMethod('GET');
                req.setTimeout(60000);

                try{
                    // callout
                    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

                    // parse coordinates from response
                    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
                    double lat = null;
                    double lon = null;
                    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
                            (parser.getText() == 'location')){
                               parser.nextToken(); // object start
                               while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT){
                                   String txt = parser.getText();
                                   parser.nextToken();
                                   if (txt == 'lat')
                                       lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                                   else if (txt == 'lng')
                                       lon = parser.getDoubleValue();
                               }

                        }
                    }

                    // update coordinates if we get back
                    if (lat != null){
                        a.JYF__Location__Latitude__s = lat;
                        a.JYF__Location__Longitude__s = lon;
                        Account tmp = New Account(ID=a.ID,JYF__Location__Latitude__s=lat,JYF__Location__Longitude__s=lon);
                        account_updater.put(tmp.id,tmp);
                        System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Error,'At the Map Adding');
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
    }
    update account_updater.values();    
        }
    }
```

No matter what I do it won't update.  In developer console it indicates future method cannot call future method, and it halts the update.  But I  dont understand why.  I dont do the update until the end is that what's stopping it?  How do I avoid?  Thanks for any help.  Note: I erased my API key on purpose, it is normally filled in properly as this used to work before I attempted to bulk it.  Thanks.

Added the Future change on trigger.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the accounts in the future method

```
update account_updater.values();
```

it fires the trigger again which attempts to call the future method again.

Easy fix is to check for system.future in the trigger

```
if(!system.isFuture() && !system.isBatch())
   LocationCallouts.getLocation(calloutIds);
```

Comment: Still gives same error 09:02:18:322 EXCEPTION_THROWN [19]|System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: JYF.LocationCallouts.getLocation(List<Id>)

Comment: Then that error did not come from the trigger (Or you di not do it right) Post your new code. What method is that line 19 in? You will need to add a check for that line as well. And with so many checks you may need to rethink your flow as well.